# Comparison, Python deque's or indexes?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

I am required to access the leftmost element of a Python `list`, while popping elements from the left. One example of this usage could be the merge operation of a merge sort.
There are two good ways of doing it.

- `collections.deque`
- Using indexes, keep an increasing integer as I pop.

Both these methods seems efficient in complexity terms (Should mention at the beginning of the program I need to convert the list to deque, meaning some extra O(n)).

So in the terms of style and speed, which is the best for Python usage ? I did not see an official recommendation or did not encounter a similar question which is why I am asking this.

Thanks in advance.

**Related:** [Time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: If your question is about speed, then the answers lie in profiling your particular use-case. You have this power in your hands.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was unsure if could implement a precise testing code. Which I am trying anyway.

Comment: Use the `timeit` module

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know the module, I wasn't sure if I could produce subtle code suited for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely `collections.deque`. First, it's already written so you don't have to. Second, it's written in C so probably it is going to be much faster than another Python re-implementation. Third, using index leaves the head of the list unused, whereas `queue` is more clever. Appending to a standard list only to increase the starting index on each left pop is very inefficient because you would need to realloc the list more often.